# IE9 and head.js loads script twice

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-9, head.js

Using **Head.js** (0.9) and verifying the loading of scripts from IE9, the Network pane of IE9 developer shows that the javascripts are loaded twice.

First time, the script is loaded with HTTP result code 200, thereafter the same script is reloaded with result code 304 (not modified).

However, the script pane and the script block drop down displays the scripts as being loaded twice. This in turn makes one of the scripts (sIFR.js) resetting its global sIFR object.

I'm suspecting the double-loading is causing this.

Note: Chrome and Firefox both work as expected.

Anyone else having seen this odd behaviour?

Comment: I know this is old, but this is still an issue using version 1.0.3 with IE8/9, did you solve it?